# setting up ACRA 5.5.1 in ReactNative 0.61.2

Tags: react-native, crash-reports, acra

I am trying to setup ACRA for my react native project which using 0.61.2 version. I followed the basic setup tutorial from https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup .

But while building the project I got errors

```
/android/app/src/main/java/com/agentnativeapp/MainApplication.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
  CoreConfigurationBuilder builder = new CoreConfigurationBuilder(this)
  ^
symbol:   class CoreConfigurationBuilder
location: class MainApplication
```

I don't understand what am I missing. I thought I might be missing the jar file, but there are no instructions showing the requirement of jar file.

I am new to JAVA side of programming so I am new to all these jar stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was all importing problem.

import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;

The above statement doesn't actually import every class, so I have to CoreConfigurationBuilder separately

import org.acra.config.CoreConfigurationBuilder;